# Proof of a closed form of $\int_0^1(-\ln x)^ndx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

$$\int_0^1(-\ln x)^ndx$$
Is there a step-by-step solution to a closed form of this expression? I've tried using different representations to re-write the expression but I couldn't find anything I knew how to simplify.

Comment: Use integration by parts:$$I_n = \int_0^1(-\ln x)^ndx = \left[x(-\ln x)^n\right]_0^1 + n\int_0^1 (-\ln x)^{n-1}\,dx = nI_{n-1}$$

Comment: That doesn't eliminate the $\ln(0)$ in the answer.

Comment: There is no $\ln 0$ in the answer. The lower limit $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x(\ln x) = 0$ !

Comment: In that case, a recursive definition simplified to a verbatim definition of a factorial is definitely a short and simple closed-form solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the integral $$I(a) = \int _{0}^{1} x^a \rm{d}x= \frac{1}{a+1} $$
Now take the derivative $n$ times and obtain $$I(a)^{(n)}= \frac{(-1)^nn!}{(a+1)^{n+1}},$$ which gives $$I(0)^{(n)} =(-1)^nn!.$$ On the other hand differentiating under the integral sign gives 
$$I(0)^{(n)}= \int _{0}^{1} \ln (x)^n \rm{d}x$$
And so conclude the result.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $$x = e^{-s}, \qquad dx = -e^s \,ds ,$$
so that the integral becomes
$$\int_0^{\infty} s^n e^{-s}\,ds.$$
But, this is a well known formula for the factorial $n!$, or for $\Gamma(n + 1)$, where $\Gamma$ is the usual [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

If one doesn't know this formula, then, at least when $n$ is a nonnegative integer, one can evaluate the integral by

1. applying integration by parts to produce a reduction formula that expresses it in terms of $$\int_0^{\infty} s^{n - 1} e^{-s} \, ds,$$ and
2. applying an induction argument.

Comment: Can't you do integration by parts to the original integral, without first doing that substitution?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, of course, I chose the substitution because the resulting form is (to me, anyway) more familiar.

Comment: Could you explain how you change the integral in the first step?

Comment: @Waffle This is just reverse substitution. The trickiest part is the limits: Since $\lim_{s \to -\infty} x = \lim_{s \to \infty} e^{-s} = 0$, $x = 0$ becomes $s = \infty$, and since $e^{-(0)} = 1$, $x = 1$ becomes $s = 0$. Does that help?