# The integral $\int_{0}^{1}\ln^n(1/x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

It is well known that
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\ln^p(1/x)\,dx=\Gamma(p+1) 
$$
In particular, if $p=n$ is a **positive** integer, then
$$
I_n:=\int_{0}^{1}\ln^n(1/x)\,dx=(n+1)!
$$
Therefore, we obtain the following recursive relation
$$
I_{n+1}=(n+1)I_n\quad;\quad I_1=1
$$
Is there an easy way, using only elementary methods, to establish that relation?

My attempt: Using integration by parts
\begin{align}
I_{n+1}&=\left[\ln^n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)x\left(1+\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\right]_{0}^{1}\\
&\qquad-\int_{0}^{1}(n+1)\ln^n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)x\left(1+\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\,dx
\end{align}
How do I continue from here ?

Comment: Something like this ? 

\begin{align*}
I_{n+1} &= \left ( n+1 \right ) I_n \\ 
 &= \left ( n+1 \right ) n I_{n-1}\\ 
 &= \left ( n+1 \right ) n \left ( n-1 \right ) I_{n-2} \\ 
 &=\cdots \\ 
 &= \left ( n+1 \right ) n \left ( n-1 \right ) \cdots 3 \cdot 2 \cdot I_{1} \\
 &=  \left ( n+1 \right ) \underbrace{n \left ( n-1 \right ) \cdots 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}_{n!} \\
 &= \left ( n+1 \right ) n! \\
 &= \left ( n+1 \right )!
\end{align*}

Comment: Of course not. How to establish the relation $I_{n+1}=(n+1)I_n$ ?

Comment: Sorry, your question is how to establish the recursion.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1082068/399263, you complicate your life using $\frac 1x$ just use $(-\ln(x))$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I_{n+1}=\int_0^1 1 \log ^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx=\left[x \log ^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]_0^1- \int_0^1 -\frac{x \left((n+1) \log ^n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}{x} \, dx=$$
$$=\left[0-\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\;x \log ^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]+(n+1)I_n=0+(n+1)I_n$$
$$I_{n+1}=(n+1)I_n$$

Comment: Thank @Raffaele.

Comment: @Raffaele is correct, integration by parts is the way to go. Slightly easier,  for me at least, to start by making the change of variable $u := \log x$.